# How to show hard disk file system format

Tags: disk, format, ext3

I want to see what file system format my hard drive uses on Ubuntu server 14.04

(Like ext2, ext3, etc..)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19671/command-line-option-to-check-which-filesystem-i-am-using

Comment: Type sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Check the type section of the drive in question. There may be other ways, but this came to mind first

Edit: another way would be

```
 Sudo blkid /dev/xxx (whatever is, ie /dev/sda1)
```