# Why the file usage decreases dramatically when the directory is copied from guest Ubuntu to usb disk?

Tags: disk-usage, restore, usb-drive

I have a VMware installed on my Windows 10, and the guest is Ubuntu. I copied a directory of 2.2G from the Ubuntu guest to my USB flash disk by this command:

```
rsync ubuntudirectory usbdirectory -r
```

But I find that the file space decreases by 1.0G.

```
du ubuntudirectory -hc
```

2.2G

```
du usbdirectory -hc
```

1.2G

What happened? There are only pure text files in the directory.

And I thought that it would be the possibly too long length of some file names that make the copy(rsync) omit some files, but it was not the fact.

```
ls usbdirectory | wc -l
```

559562

```
ls ubuntudirectory | wc -l
```

560213

Most likely the files are almost of the same size, so the files failed to be transferred seems hardly a cause of the large shrinking disk space.

To make sure that it is not the ignored files that effect the shrink(as @Anwar suspected), I have tried to reproduce it using one more directory which is much smaller. The decrease is 10M from 17M to 6.8M. **The two directories are of just the same amount of files(the exact amount is 8948)**. After rsynced back to the guest disk(from the usb), the directory recovered from 6.8M to 17M.

```
du /home/myname/somewhere/text -hc
```

17M

```
rsync /home/myname/somewhere/text /media/myname/UUI/text  -r

du /media/myname/UUI/text -hc
```

6.8M

```
rsync /media/myname/UUI/text /home/myname/text -r

du /home/myname/text -hc
```

17M

Comment: you were copying, why would it decrease?

Comment: @Anwar That's what I have been plagued by.

Comment: The files weren't in the usb first. that's why it's not a decrease, rather not required increase. It failed to copy something. Your title is misleading

Comment: No, I crawled the text files from the Internet and each text a file, even same thousand files decrease cannot effect the space usage in such a large scale.

Comment: I have also tried to copy a smaller directory from ubuntu to the usb disk with some normal length file names, the size also decreased. You can reproduce it yourself.

Comment: Copy files back in the other direction. What happened to `du` results?

Comment: @techraf The result increases to be the same as before. That's, the 6.8M directory becomes back to 17M when resynced to my guest.

Comment: ...and what's the filesystem on USB? Sorry, I asked that before under my answer.

Comment: @techraf Sorry I cannot find the filesystem type by checking the usb's properties.

Comment: Of course you can't. You just need to read the output of `mount` http://askubuntu.com/questions/19671/command-line-option-to-check-which-filesystem-i-am-using

Comment: The output is like this: `type fuseblk (rw, nosuid, nodev, allow_other, default_permissions, blksize=4096)`

Comment: You are using.NTFS. It's impossible to answer your question based on the information you provided. You don't mention how does a free space value change for the drive when you copy or remove the files. The filesystem on the drive might be composed, or not. What's sure is that `du` returns approximate results and it is expected that they differ between drives and filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are written in blocks consisting of a multitude of 512 bytes, for example 1kB, 4 kB. Block size differs between filesystems and disk sizes. The larger the disk, the larger the block. A file containing 1.5 kB of data will occupy 1.5 kB of disk space on a filesystem with a block size of 512 kB, 2 kB on a filesystem with 1 kB blocks, 4 kB on a filesystem with 4 kB blocks.

`du` command displays an estimation of the disk space of all the blocks occupied by the files.

If (especially if) you have a large number of small files the space reserved in a block at the end of each file, but not used by the data, will be larger on disks/filesystems with a large block size (larger disks).

You can check the block size for a particular device with:

```
sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. I have tried your suggestions and here are the results: `sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdb` and `sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1` both give me the same number, 4096. And the former is where my usbdirectory lies and the later my ubuntudirectory.

Comment: @lerneradams what is the filesystem on USB drive?